# I need to press Ctrl+C every time to run next Class in my shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

In my shell script I am compiling/running two program i.e "VertxLauncher.java" and "FileGeneratorVerticle.java" but after running the first one I need to press Ctrl+C every time to run next Class FileGeneratorVerticle.java

How do I automate this task..

Thanks in advance..

```
clear

lib_dir=/desktop/RunnableJarFiles




export CLASSPATH=.:${CLASSPATH}:${lib_dir}/c360-.jar:${lib_dir}/c360A-.jar:${lib_dir}/c360-verticle.jar
javac -classpath $CLASSPATH  com.VertxLauncher.java
java -classpath $CLASSPATH  com.VertxLauncher "start"


javac -classpath $CLASSPATH   com.verticles.FileGeneratorVerticle.java
java  -classpath $CLASSPATH   com.verticles.FileGeneratorVerticle $INPUT_FILE $FILE_PATH $DAT_FILE_PATH
```

Comment: If the control is not coming back automatically and if you're not bothered about the success of first compilation for executing the second one then you can simply trigger the process in the background. Just add a "&" at the end of the line which you want to trigger in background.

Comment: You could also use a command named timeout.